# The RavenDb Limits

Tags: lucene, ravendb, nosql

My system need to create ~1billion of documents per year divided in 5 types of documents.
I have a multimap index which queries the 5 types of documents. This index will represent ~20billions references/year.

Is RavenDb able to assume a such quantity of data ?
It seems that Lucene has the capability to handle approximately 2.1 billion documents as an upper limit.
There are also a 16To limit per database, this is a problem for me.

What is the solution for my problem ? Do i need to change of NoSQL database system ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at sharding the data across multiple nodes.
I would suggest roughly 50 - 100 million docs per node, depending on your load.

Comment: But the problem will be the same with the documents IDs, isn't it ? Is it just a solution for the 16To limit ?